# Comparing dictionaries while excluding certain keys

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
let foo: [String: Any] = ["name": "John", "isHuman": true, "age": 20]
let bar: [String: Any] = ["name": "Ann", "isHuman": true, "age": 34]
```

that I would like to compare while excluding certain keys from that comparison. The keys that I want to exclude are in another dictionary:

```
let car: [String: Any] = ["age": 20]
```

I have this extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding: [Key] = []) -> Bool {
      let left = filter({ !excluding.contains($0.key) })
      let right = dictionary.filter({ !excluding.contains($0.key) })
      return NSDictionary(dictionary: left).isEqual(to: right)
    }
}
```

but when I call it, I need to wrap the excluded keys in `Array`, otherwise the compiler fails with:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary.Keys' to expected argument type '[String]'

`foo.isEqualTo(bar, excluding: Array(car.keys))` works.

`foo.isEqualTo(bar, excluding: car.keys)` results in a compiler error.

Can I adjust my extension in a way that will allow me to avoid wrapping the excluded keys in `Array`?

Comment: How about `func isEqualTo(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding: Dictionary.Keys) -> Bool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`car.keys` has the type `Dictionary<Key, Value>.Keys`, which is a
*collection* and not an array.

If you declare the function as

```
func isEqualTo<C: Collection>(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding: C) -> Bool
        where C.Element == Key
```

then both

```
foo.isEqualTo(bar, excluding: Array(car.keys))
foo.isEqualTo(bar, excluding: car.keys)
```

compile and work.

Comment: This has the extra benefit of being able to pass in a plain array of strings, for example. Nice. But how can this updated so `excluding` has a default value like the original?

Comment: @maddy I updated it to `wmf_isEqualTo<C: Collection>(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding excludedKeys: C? = nil) -> Bool where C.Element == Key` and guarded against excludedKeys being nil and returning `NSDictionary(dictionary: self).isEqual(to: dictionary)` if that's the case

Comment: Yes, `excludedKeys: C? = nil` is what I was about to suggest.

Comment: There is also an  `EmptyCollection` type, but `excluding: C = EmptyCollection<Key>()` does not compile ...

Answer (score 2):

Declare `excluding` to be of type `Keys`.

```
func isEqualTo(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding: Keys = [:].keys) -> Bool {
```

As a side note, you can eliminate the use of `NSDictionary` by updating your code as:

```
let foo: [String: AnyHashable] = ["name": "John", "isHuman": true, "age": 20]
let bar: [String: AnyHashable] = ["name": "Ann", "isHuman": true, "age": 34]

let car: [String: Any] = ["age": 20, "name":"Bob"]

extension Dictionary where Key: Equatable, Value: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ dictionary: Dictionary, excluding: Keys = [:].keys) -> Bool {
        let left = filter({ !excluding.contains($0.key) })
        let right = dictionary.filter({ !excluding.contains($0.key) })
        return left == right
    }
}
```

Note the use of `AnyHashable` instead of `Any` for the dictionaries and note the added `, Value: Equatable` in the extension.

Comment: I had tried `Value: Equatable` but did not think of `AnyHashable`. That's better than using NSDictionary.

Comment: `[:].keys` yikes. I know what it means, and why it's valid, but that really seems like abuse of the syntax :p

Comment: @Alexander I'd love to know a better way to create an empty instance of `Keys`.

Comment: @rmaddy You could spell it out: `Dictionary().keys` Not sure that's much better, but it's a bit less cryptic for the uninitiated.